# Bypassing ZwTerminateProcess hooks

Tags: windows, process, hook, terminate

I'm writing a program that will terminate any given process.
Link to my code : [Link](http://paste.org/66392)

I expect it to terminate any process, bypassing any hooks.
But security softwares can still block terminating (I've tested with sandboxie and processguard so far)?

I can't understand how they can do that. My program rewrites functions and I expect to remove hooks this way.

How can I bypass hooks? What do I miss in this code?

P.S : This program crashes in third ZwTerminateProcess call. Can someone help about this, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are doing is engaging in a game of walls and ladders. Next will be an app that wants to hook termination, even if your app is disabling hooks. The battle is never over. And none of this is supported. If you describe your actual problem, maybe we can develop a solution.

Comment: My actual problem is stated in the question. I'm just writing a small console tool that kills any given pid, for learning purposes. At the moment, I don't have any plan to implement answers to some other tool.

Comment: You didn't mention "for learning purposes" in the original question. I was wondering whether there was some production problem you were trying to solve where you think terminating a process and bypassing hooks was going to fix it. (If you find a way to terminate and bypass hooks, the next person is going to ask, "How can I hook terminate, even if somebody is trying to bypass hooks?")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, AV and sandboxing software will end up modifying function pointer tables in the kernel. Short of writing a driver, there is no easy way to get around that, because the functionality may be disabled system-wide (what AV's do) or for a particular application (what sandboxes would do).

If you are actually able to open a handle to the process, you can still do a lot of things. Maybe you could try killing it indirectly. I would try to write directly to the process' memory and overwrite it with garbage (or calls to ExitProcess).

Comment: But It rewrites original instructions? Won't this help?

Comment: You are rewriting user (ring 3) code in a user process, though. So you are not actually restoring the changes in the kernel (ring 0) structures. All you're doing is changing the code for a DLL that Windows decided to load into memory.

If the sandbox is simply overwriting those user instructions (which I doubt), then your approach will work. But that is likely not the case.

Comment: And how can I restore kernel structures? Using a kernel-mode driver?

Comment: Yes, that is the only option.

Comment: Can you tell me please, what must I do in my driver?

Comment: I'm not an expert in writing drivers, but *from what I've read* you want to monitor the SSDT (and the shadow) for any hooks, and reverse them. You have to be careful that you don't reverse all hooks, because a legitimate application might also make hooks. Take this with a grain of salt, because I have never needed to do anything like this before.